# Do include guards mean that only one .cpp file gets the header content?

Tags: c++, include-guards

When I include a header file, lets say,

```
//myheader.h
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

//....

#endif
```

into,

```
//mycpp1.cpp
#include "myheader.h"
```

What I'm told is, when mycpp1.cpp includes myheader.h, `MY_HEADER_H` gets defined so any attempt to include it again will result false.

Now, if i want to include it in mycpp2.cpp.

```
//mpcpp2.cpp
#include "myheader.h"
```

Would it get included or does it use the same declarations when it was included the first time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preprocessor definitions are seperate for each file. So if you `#include` myheader.h into two seperate .cpp files, it will be included twice, not once. One per .cpp.

Comment: Thats what was my guess.. is there any way I can check to see if it gets included twice?

Comment: @user974191 you can look at the files after the preprocessor gets done with them, but why do you want to?

Comment: Do you mean object files? Nothing just trying to understand what goes on.

Comment: @user974191 no. As you probably know, the preprocessor gets a hold of every file before it is compiled and replaces `#define`s, replaces `#include`s with the contents of the files that are `#include`d, etc. To view how many times your file is included, you can put a comment outside the #include guards of a that file, then view the output of the preprocessor and see how many times the comment appears. So for gcc, you'd do `gcc -E file.cpp` and that will give you what the preprocessor outputs, and you can count the number of times it appears.

Comment: @user974191 how to view the output of the preprocessor will be different for each compiler/platform. Like I said for gcc it has the `-E` flag, for Visual Studio it's probably a project setting.

Answer (score 4):

> Preprocessor defines are local to the current compilation unit.

Of course there are complex cases, but here is the point:

Try to look at .cpp (source) files as distinct entities.
If you don't make really weird things, then
if you remove all .cpp files except the one you bother,
you can stil compile, because in the compiling stage no need
for definitions, you care only the name (*declaration*) of things.

So, compiling N source files in one run is essentially this:

```
[ *.H + SOURCE1.CPP ] --> SOURCE1.O
[ *.H + SOURCE2.CPP ] --> SOURCE2.O
...
[ *.H + SOURCEN.CPP ] --> SOURCEN.O
```

where every line is a distinct *compilation unit*, which
renders the SourceX.CPP and the included headers into an Object file.
So we got here N separate thing.

This way, if you don't change the common headers, then you don't have to
recompile unmodified source files. Of course, if you modify a source file,
you have to recompile that. And finally, if you modify a common header, then you have
to recompile every source file that included it.
Here I have to mention, that before the compiling phase, all
`#inlude "filename.ext"` line (*preprocessor directive*) will be replaced
with the exact content of the filename.ext file, whatever it is.

Then linking is a different problem, in that stage
the goal is to create one single file from that N object files. *(I repeat, this is the simple case)*

This is linking:

```
[ SOURCE1.O + SOURCE2.O + ... + SOURCEN.O ]  --> EXECUTABLE.FILE
```

Imagine the affected the object files as a bag of values and
algorithms (*function definitions*). For example, somewhere in the bag there must be exactly one
`main` function (*definition*), so the linker will definitely know what
to do when you execute the program.

Hope you got it

Guess what happens, if you write a global function's definition into a header file,
and then you include it in two separate compilation unit, then you try to link them.

The Answer: linker error - multiple definitions, since you can compile them separately.

Answer (score 3):

If **MY_HEADER_H** is just defined in mycpp1.cpp, the header file will be included in mycpp2.cpp

what the trick is really for is like:

> **header1.h** includes **header2.h**.
>   So when you include both **header1.h** and **header2.h** in your mycpp.cpp, 
>   **header2.h** will be included twice if you did not do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As the other have stated, the header file is included once per .cpp file. But I also wanted to mention that the whole purpose of this:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H
// ..
#end if
```

is to prevent this from causing a problem

*mycpp1.cpp*

```
#include "myheader.h"
#include "myheader.h"
// ...
```

another thing I had trouble with when I started was when you include your header file in more than one .cpp file and have global variables defined in it... here's what I do to solve that...

*myheader.h*

```
#ifdef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

#ifdef GLOBAL_EXTERN
extern int nGlobalInt;
#else
int nGlobalInt = 282;
#endif

#endif
```

*mycpp1.cpp*

```
#include "myheader.h"
// ...

cout << nGlobalInt;
```

*mycpp2.cpp*

```
#define GLOBAL_EXTERN
#include "myheader.h"
// ...

cout << nGlobalInt;
```

both cpp files will print `282`

Comment: Without the `#ifdef GLOBAL_EXTERN ...` you would get redefinition error with your compiler.

Comment: it's more straight-forward if you define `nGlobalInt` inside *one* of the cpp files and get rid of `GLOBAL_EXTERN`. extern acts as a forward-declare for that variable instance.

Comment: @Victor T., Agreed... But for the contexts of this question, I thought this example would be better.

Answer (score -1):

It will be included only once. The directive MY_HEADER_H would get defined on the first inclusion and all subsequent attempts to `#include` myheader.h would have no effect.

The preprocessor directives prevail across files. Otherwise, for example, every class declared in myheader.h, would be redefined.